# Find $f''(x)$ if $f\circ f'(x) = 4x^2 + 3$

Tags: derivatives, functional-equations, function-and-relation-composition

Can you tell me the solution of this question?

> If: $f\circ f'(x)=4 x^2 +3$
>
> then what is $f''(x)$?

This was a question in math test which I just took yesterday.

One function satisfying the equation above is $f(x)=x^2+3$, for which $f'(x)=2x$ and therefore $f''(x)=2$.

We can also see that $f'(x)$ is monotonic in $[0,+\infty)$, and in $(-\infty,0]$.

What other analytic solutions $f(x)$ exist ?
Can we express all analytic solutions $f(x)$ with a few parameters ?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Please format your equations with MathJax.  [Check here for a tutorial.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! To attract answers to your question, please add some context and background information. For example, where did you encounter this problem (e.g. a book, class, real-life)? Please also show your attempt; seeing your work helps us help you. If this is homework, please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/23353).

Comment: Don't worry if your question got put on hold. You might still get an answer. Your question is interesting. I will try to solve it. If I can I will give you the solution. The question seems hard though.

Comment: One can by not much playing find an $f$ that works. I have not checked whether it is the only one.

Comment: I cant answer this question because its on hold :(

Comment: I do not think this is homework since its about composition.
Although it may have an origin/inspiration from homework.

Comment: It's worth noting that since if $f'(x)=f'(y)$ we must have $x^2=y^2$ we can strengthen your statement to "$f'$ is either monotonic on $[0,\infty)$ and satisfies $f(-x)=-f(x)$, or is monotonic on $(-\infty,\infty)$"

Comment: @mick, the question is open now.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki $\frac{(f\circ f)'}{f'} = f' \circ f$ though

Comment: @Dylan D'oh, you're right; I got sloppy with my chain-ruling.

Comment: @Pp.. , thanks for your answer! But how you found the equation for f(x) ? I know the answer is right.but, well Im not good at answering math with 'guess and check' :/ –

Comment: @mick,And,no this is not homework.it was a question in my semester final exam of basic math for pharmacy.

Comment: What does this have to do with pharmacy ? :)

Comment: @rose The question must likely has a mistake and it is $f(x)f'(x)$ instead of $f(f'(x))$. This way it is simpler to solve and seems more likely for an exam. For $f(f'(x))$ you can see that $f(x)=x^2+3$ works. But finding all possible solutions or proving this is the only one, seems hard.

Comment: @rose On the other hand if the problem were $f(x)f'(x)=4x^2+3$ then we see that $2f(x)f'(x)=8x^2+6$. But $2f(x)f'(x)=(f(x)^2)'$. Therefore $f(x)^2=8x^3/3+3x+C$. Then $f(x)=\sqrt{8x^3/3+3x+C}$ and one can compute the possible values of $f''(x)$ from there.

Comment: @mick, you wanted to answer the question 13 hours ago. now you come back ask what it has to do with pharmacy?

Answer (score 5):

we will show that the only smooth solution to the problem $f(f'(x)) = 4x^2 + 3 $ is $f(x) = x^2 + 3.$

the differentiable function $f$ is defined by 
$$ f(f^\prime(x)) = 4x^2 + 3.\tag 1$$ 
differentiating $(1)$ gives 
$$[f^\prime(f^\prime(x)) ] * f^{\prime \prime}(x)= 8x \tag 2  $$
differentiating $(2)$ gives 
$$[f^\prime(f^\prime(x))]*f^{\prime \prime \prime}(x) + 
\left( f^{\prime \prime} (x)\right)^2 f^{\prime \prime}(f^\prime(x))= 8 \tag 3$$
 we will note that the range of $f$ is contained in $[3, \infty)$ and in fact $3$ is in the range of $f$ because putting $x = 0$ in $(1)$ gives 
$$f(f^\prime(0)) = 3, \ \ f^\prime(f^\prime(0)) = 0\tag 4$$
 the second equality follows  if we recognize that $3$ is a global minimum of $f.$

putting $x=0$ in $(3)$ and making use of  $(4)$ shows that 
$f^{\prime \prime}(0) \neq 0.$
 more is true. in fact we will show that 
$$ f^{\prime \prime}(x) \neq 0 \tag 5$$

suppose there is an $a$ such that $f^{\prime \prime}(a) = 0.$ putting $x = a$ in $(2)$ shows $a = 0.$ but we already showed that $f^{\prime \prime}(0) \neq 0$ and that establishes $(5).$  we can improve $(5)$ and will show that 
$$ f^{\prime \prime}(0) = 2,\ \ f^{\prime \prime}(x) > 0 \text {  for all } x. \tag {5b} $$
this follows simply by putting $x = 0$ in $(3)$

we will now show that the only local extremum on the graph is $(0, 3)$

suppose $x=a$ is a local extremum. then by $(1)$ we have $a = \pm \sqrt{f(0) - 3}$. if these are distinct, then by rolle's thorem, there will be a point $c$ between them at which $f^{\prime \prime}(c) = 0$ contradicting $(5b).$
this tells us that 
$$f(0) = 3, f^\prime (0) = 0, f^{\prime \prime }(0) = 2, xf^\prime(x) > 0 \text{ for } x \neq 0, f^{\prime \prime}(x) > 0 \text{ for all } x. \tag 6$$

differentiating $(3)$ we get

$$[f^\prime(f^\prime (x)]*f^{(4)}(x) +
f^{(3)}(x) f^{(2)}(f^\prime(x))f^{(2)}(x) +
2f^{(3)}(x) f^{(2)}(x)f^{(2)}(f^\prime(x) + 
f^{3}(f^\prime(x))(f^{(2)}(x))^3 = 0 
\tag 7$$

observe that in both $(3)$ and $(7)$ the highest order derivative is multiplied by $[f^\prime(f^\prime(x))]$ which is zero at $x = 0$ it can be seen that this persists for all orders.

now putting $x = 0$ in $(7)$ and making use of $(6)$ gives us 
$4f^{(3)}(0) + 8 f^{(3)}(0) + 8f^{(3)}(0) = 0 $ which implies that $$f^{(3)}(0) = 0 $$

continuing this way i think i can show that $$f^{(n)}(0) = 0 \text{ for } n = 3, 4, 5, \cdots \tag 8$$ 
but it may be easier to expand 
$$f(x) = 3 + x^2 + 2a_4x^4 + 2a_5x^5 +  \cdots  $$

$$f^\prime(x) = 2x\left(1 +  + 4a_4x^2 + 5a_5x^3 +  \cdots \right) $$

putting these in $(1)$ we get

$$3 + 4x^2 = 3 + 4x^2 \left( 1 + 4a_4x^2 + 5a_5x^3 +  \cdots \right)^2 
+ 2a_4(2x)^4  \left( 1 +  4a_4x^2 + 5a_5x^3 +  \cdots \right)^4 
+ 5a_5 (2x)^5 \left( 1 +  4a_4x^2 + 5a_5x^3 +  \cdots \right)^5+ \cdots $$

equating the coefficient of $x^4$ gives $a_4 = 0.$ now remove $a_4$ and show $a_5 = 0$ and by induction we should be able to show $(8)$.

p.s. thanks to the op for posting this problem.

the proof in the last stages can be streamlined using the following claim.

claim: if $f(x) = 3 + x^2 + 2ax^k, k \ge 3,$ then $a = 0.$

proof:

$\begin{align}
3 + 4x^2 &= f(f^\prime (x)) = f(2x(1 + akx^{k-2})) \\ 
 &= 3 + 4x^2(1 +kax^{k-2})^2 + 2a*(2x)^k(1 + kax^{k-2})^k\\ 
 &= 3 + 4x^2 + 8akx^k + 4k^2 a^2 x^{2k-2} + 2^{k+1}ax^k + \cdots \\ 
 &= 3 + 4x^2 + a(8k + 2^{k+1})x^k + \cdots 
\end{align}$

which implies $ a = 0.$  this could be used to cut short the proof of $(8).$

Answer (score 1):

I think I have an (incomplete and not rigorous) heuristic which suggests that $f(x)=x^2+3$ is the only answer. Perhaps somebody can turn this into a proper/rigorous answer.

It starts with the assumption that $f$ is analytic:

$$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i,$$
so that
$$f'(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty ia_ix^{i-1}.$$

If we write an expression for $f(f'(x))$ we get something like
$$\begin{align}
f(f'(x))&=a_0+a_1(a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+4a_4x^3+\cdots)
\\&\phantom{=}+a_2(a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+4a_4x^3+\cdots)^2
\\&\phantom{=}+a_3(a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+4a_4x^3+\cdots)^3+\cdots
\end{align}$$

If we can argue at this point (this is the big hole!) that all of the $a_n=0$ for $n\geq 3$ we are basically there. If this is true we have that $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2$. Just by plugging in we see that $a_2\neq 0$ and if $a_2\neq 0$ then $a_1=0$.

We plug $f(x)=a_0+a_2x^2$ into the relation and we are left with $a_0=3$ and $a_2^3=1\Rightarrow a_2=1$.

Comment: Before composing the series we must prove $f'(0)=0$, i.e. $a_1=0$. Otherwise we can't compose the series. After that it is easy to show (just compose the series) that $a_0=3, a_2=1$ and $a_n=0$, for $n>2$.

Comment: @Jp McCarthy, thanks for the anwer!

Comment: @mick,Im studying pharmacy and Im in the first year.our math course title is 'basic math for pharmacy students'.what it has to do with pharmacy,maybe I can find the answer in upper years ;)

Comment: @Pp.. , thank you for all the help ! :)

Comment: @Pp.. Why do we have to do that be before composing the series?

Comment: @JpMcCarthy Can you compute any term of the series of $f(f'(x))$, if a_1\neq0? For example, the constant term would be $a_0+a_1a_0+a_2a_0^2+...$. On one hand that doesn't help you  to find the coefficients $a_i$, on the other hand it is not clear the series converge. Very often it doesn't.

Comment: There are bigger problems than $a_1$ really... how do you argue that $a_3=0$? Note I don't consider this a satisfactory answer myself.

Comment: How do you conclude that a_2 is not 0 and that a_1 must be 0 ?
I found some typo's in your equations, not sure if that relates. @JpMcCarthy

Comment: I think one needs to prove that a_n >= 0 for all n.
Assuming there is a unique analytic solution ...

Comment: @mick I don't think you have read my 'answer' properly...

Comment: @JpMcCarthy you mean you first assume a_n = 0 for n >=3 and then conclude ... I assume.
I see.
But I still think we need to show a_n >= 0.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the function defined by

- $f(x)=3+x^2$ if $x\le 0$
- $f(x)=3-x^2$ if $x\ge 0$

is also continuous, and $f(f'(x))=3+4x^2$ also. But then

- $f''(x)=2$ if $x<0$
- $f''(x)=-2$ if $x>0$
- $f''$ is not defined for $x=0$

Answer (score -2):

Together with the 2 answers already given here , for completeness I add this relevant link

[Can $f(g(x))$ be a polynomial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115663/can-fgx-be-a-polynomial)

That should make everything clear.