# Can $f(g(x))$ be a polynomial?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, taylor-expansion, function-and-relation-composition

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be nonpolynomial real-entire functions.

Is it possible that $f(g(x))$ is equal to a polynomial ?

***edit***

Some comments :

I was thinking about iterations.

So for instance $f(f(x)) = $ some polynomial.

However such $f$ are usually (Always ?) not entire because of the fact that a non-linear polynomial has more than 1 fixpoint.

This lead me to consider adding the strong condition

$(f(g(x)) - g(f(x)))^2$ is not indentically $0$.

But I guess that is a followup question.

***edit 2***

Real-entire means entire and real-analytic.

Comment: I assume the singularities at oo for f and g make this impossible.

Comment: If $g=f^{-1}$, for one.

Comment: @Arthur but $f^{-1}$ might not be entire !

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "real entire"?

Comment: What's a "real entire" function? The restriction of an entire function to the real line? Need it also be real-valued there?

Comment: Yes its an entire function that maps all the reals to some reals. In other words real-analytic + entire.

Comment: What about $f(x)=\exp(x)$ and $g(x) = \ln(x^2+1)$?

Comment: @AlexR. your g is not entire.

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry, got that wrong.

Comment: ...what is wrong with $\ln(x^2+1)$???

Comment: @JpMcCarthy its not an entire function !

Comment: @mick I think the log of a non-zero entire function is entire...

Comment: But x^2 + 1 does have zero's on the complex plane !

Comment: Ah yes correct you are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are various ways to show that this can not be true. E.g., by Casorati-Weierstrass, the image of $|z|>R$ under $g$ is dense in the plane for every $R>0$, so the image of the same domain under $f\circ g$ contains a dense subset of $f(\mathbb{C})$ which is itself dense in the plane, showing that $f \circ g$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$.

(And it does not matter that $f$ and $g$ are real.)

Comment: I think this answer is correct.
Basically this is what I expected , see my first comment.
THANK YOU !